# Sqlpackage throwing error without details

Tags: ssms, sqlpackage, bacpac, data-tier-applications

I am currently working on an application to easily restore a bacpac file. Unfortunately i have the following issue: Sqlpackage throws a error that it cannot import a database because it contains one or more user objects, but when i restore the bacpac using SSMS, then it gives me the detailed error message: Invalid column IncSetCost.

Is it possible that sqlpackage can give me the same error message (example: using a extra command/switch) without using SSMS for detailed error message or is there a orther utility that can restore a bacpac with more detailed error message.

Error message sqlpackage: [image]
Error message SSMS (import data-tier) [image]

Greetings,
Stefan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check below 2 options:

This will help exporting detailed diagnostic information to console or to a file.

/Diagnostics:   /d  {True|False}    Specifies whether diagnostic logging is output to the console. Defaults to False.

/DiagnosticsFile:   /df {string}    Specifies a file to store diagnostic logs.

For older versions of sqlpackage.exe [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/9bd61353-4a4d-4363-a246-5225e9ff1e6a/sqlpackageexe-output-errors-and-warnings-to-file?forum=ssdt) should work.